# C# - Convert one Enum to an other

Tags: c#, enums

I have 2 enums

```
public enum PersonTitle{
   Mr=0,Ms=1,Mrs=2
}

public enum SystemPersonTitles{
   Mr=0,Ms=1,Mrs=2
}
```

How do I convert one to an other **(no Switch cases or If Statements)**.

```
public void SystemPersonTitles TellWhatYouAre(PersonTitle personTitle){
//here
}
//usage
SystemPersonTitles systemPersonTitles = TellWhatYouAre(PersonTitle.Ms);
```

Comment: The values are the same, so you can just cast it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SystemPersonTitles newValue = (SystemPersonTitles)(int)PersonTitle.Mr;
```

Out of the head, I cannot test this as I'm currently on my OSX.

Answer (score 8):

Enums are just glorified integers, so you can simply cast from one to another:

```
public SystemPersonTitles TellWhatYouAre(PersonTitle personTitle)
{
    return (SystemPersonTitles)personTitle;
}
```

Note that this conversion is based on the int values, not the names.

Answer (score 3):

Cast it to an `int` and then back to the other Enum.

```
public void SystemPersonTitles TellWhatYouAre(PersonTitle personTitle){
    int value = (int)personTitle;
    var systemPersonTitle = (SystemPersonTitles)value;
}
```

Can also be done directly, as others point out, but **I wanted to be explicit to show the mechanics behind the solution**.

```
SystemPersonTitles systemPersonTitle = (SystemPersonTitles)personTitle;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since both are basically an int, you can just cast it.

So if you have a instance of `PersonTitle` called `title`, you can do this:

```
SystemPersonTitles newTitle = (SystemPersonTitles)title;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert them by value, you can use this:

```
(SystemPersonTitles)PersonTitle.Mr;
```

If you want to convert them by name, you can use this:

```
public bool TryConvertToSystemPersonTitles(
    PersonTitle personTitle, out SystemPersonTitles result)
{
    return Enum.TryParse(personTitle.ToString(), out result);
}
```

Comment: @dtb: I wrote it one way, then changed to a different way. :o Guess I left stray code in.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
PersonTitle person = PersonTitle.Mr;

SystemPersonTitles system = (int) person;
```

This will do conversion according the int value.

If you want to do it by Name, do :

```
PersonTitle person = PersonTitle.Mr;

SystemPersonTitles sys = (SystemPersonTitles)Enum.Parse(person.GetType(), person.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do it, and it's the right way. let say you could do:

```
personTitle = systemPersonTitle;
```

what would happen to your code if SystemPersonTitles will change to any one of those:

```
public enum SystemPersonTitles1{
   Mr=1,Ms=2,Mrs=3
}

public enum SystemPersonTitles2{
   Mr=0,Ms=1,Mrs=2,UnKnown=3
}

public enum SystemPersonTitles3{
   Mrs=0,Ms=1,Mr=2
}
```

Or any other change one may think of.
sure you can bypass this limitation, but it's just bad programming. If you chose to use the "int" value of them and loss the enum ability. just use "int" to begin with...

Answer (score 0):

Something like (SystemPersonTitles )(int)personTitle